# Add lines of transparent pixels to image using command line

Tags: macos, image, bash, imagemagick

I have a few 15x15 PNGs that I need to convert to 18x18 PNGs.

However, I don't want to simply scale the entire image up.

What I want is basically keep the exact old image, but "pad" it with lines of invisible/transparent pixels.

So let's say the original image looked like this (imagine the `X`s are pixels):

```
XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
```

I want to turn it into something like this (`X` being pixels of original image, `T` being new transparent pixels):

```
XXXXT
XXXXT
XXXXT
XXXXT
TTTTT
```

Is this possible using command-line tools (so that this can be automated), perhaps with something like imagemagick?

Comment: I think this rather belongs to SuperUser.

Comment: @H2CO3: depends on whether or not you consider bash to be a programming language, I guess. Feel free to move this.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that what your looking for is something like `convert -extend ....` (imagemagick). But I'm no expert...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
convert input_file -background transparent -extent '18x18' output_file
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with ImageMagick's `-append` and `+append` operators. `-append` appends to the vertically (bottom), `+append` appends horizontally (right):

```
convert \
  -background transparent \
   15x15.png \
   null: null: null: +append \
   null: null: null: -append \
   18x18.png
```

The `null:` picture is an ImageMagick built-in: it represents a 1 transparent pixel.

But as usually is the case with IM: there are a thousand ways to reach the same goal.

Should you ever need to add the transparent parts to the left and top (instead of the right and bottom), or should you want to add the pixels to just one, or to three or to four (instead of only two edges, it should be obvious to you how to modify my command.

Maybe you find Theodros' answer more intuitive (+1 on for it!). In this case, should you want to change the borders where you add your pixels, you can add the `-gravity` parameter to his command:

```
convert infile -background transparent -gravity southeast -extent '18x18' outfile
```

Other than `south`, you can also use `north`, `northeast`, `east`, ... and `northwest`. Not to forget `center`...